# TypeError: list indices must be inegers or slices, not str (Riot Games Python API)

Tags: python, typeerror, riot-games-api

I have tried many potential solutions offered on the site and across google but none have given me any success. I'm trying to pull a specific item from a list following a request to Riot Games API.

My code is:

```
lol_watcher = LoLWatcher('<API_KEY>')

my_region = 'na1'

me = lol_watcher.summoner.by_name(my_region, 'doublelift')

my_ranked_stats = lol_watcher.league.by_summoner(my_region, me['id'])

print(my_ranked_stats)
```

This outputs the following:

```
[{'leaguId': <leagueID>, 'queueType': <queueType>, 'tier': <tier>,...}]
```

My issue comes in when I try and `print` only `'tier'`:
`print(my_ranked_stats['tier'])`

If I build that way, it throws `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`.

Any help with this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the `my_ranked_stats` is a **list**. The `'tier'` key exists in the *dictionary* that is the first first element of the `my_ranked_stats` list. So you have to access `['tier']` from the zeroth index of the list like this:

```
print(my_ranked_stats[0]['tier'])
```

Comment: Thank you. I feel like a proper idiot now but thanks!